# Group Same Name products on Grid in Magento

Tags: admin, grid, products, product-collection

I am showing products on grid.Now i am facing problem .I want to group the the same title products.
My code is :

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
  {
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                  ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $this->setCollection($collection);
      return parent::_prepareCollection();
  }

  protected function _prepareColumns()
  {

      $this->addColumn('name', array(
          'header'    => Mage::helper('module')->__('Product Name'),
          'align'     =>'left',
          'index'     => 'name'
      ));

      $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
          'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Products Ids'),
          'align'     =>'left',
          'width'     => '200px',
          'index'     => 'entity_id',
      ));

        $this->addColumn('action',
            array(
                'header'    =>  Mage::helper('module')->__('Action'),
                'width'     => '100',
                'type'      => 'action',
                'getter'    => 'getId',
                'actions'   => array(
                    array(
                        'caption'   => Mage::helper('module')->__('View Details'),
                        'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/view'),
                        'field'     => 'id'
                    )
                ),
                'filter'    => false,
                'sortable'  => false,
                'index'     => 'stores',
                'is_system' => true,
        ));

      return parent::_prepareColumns();
  }
```

I want to to skip product name if it matches but show his id on Products ids with some like `(1,2,3)` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my example I added an additional column called `entity_id_grouped` both in the SELECT statement as well as the grid as you may not want do mess around with the original `entity_id` column in some cases.

First, **add the column** to your grid in `_prepareColumns()`:

```
$this->addColumn('entity_id_grouped',
    array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Product Ids'),
        'align' =>'left',
        'width' => '200px',
        'index' => 'entity_id_grouped',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_groupedEntityIdsFilter')
));
```

Note that I changed the column type to `text`. The `filter_condition_callback` parameter defines a custom method that is called when you filter for this column.

Next, **group the results** by `name` and use the built-in method to **concatenate the product IDs** in `_prepareCollection()`:

```
$collection->groupByAttribute('name');
Mage::getResourceHelper('core')->addGroupConcatColumn(
    $collection->getSelect(),
    'entity_id_grouped',
    '`e`.entity_id'
);
```

Finally, add the mentioned method `_groupedEntityIdsFilter()` to be able to **filter by product ids**:

```
protected function _groupedEntityIdsFilter($collection, $column)
{
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return $this;
    }

    $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->having(
        "GROUP_CONCAT(`e`.entity_id SEPARATOR ',') LIKE ?"
        , "%$value%");


    return $this;
}
```

---

Before the modification:

[image: Grid before the modification]

After the modification:

[image: Grid after the modification]